# Proving function f(z) to be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to solve it.

> Suppose f(z) is analytic for $|z|\leq 1$ and $|f(z)|\geq 1$ for $ |z|\leq1$ . If f(0) =1 then show that f(z) is constant.

I am sorry but for this particular question I have no clue which theorem I should use. I am completely clueless.

Kindly tell about what theorem should I use. Rest I would like to work by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use minimum modulus principle which will imply that $|f(z)| =1$ only when $|z|=1$ otherwise $f$ is constant. Since $f(0)=1$. Hence, minimum of $|f(z)|$ is achieved at an interior point, therefore, $f$ is constant.